# Combination into a file done in powershell (String + Variable)

Tags: string, function, variables, powershell, text-files

My question is related about how can I write a line that combines a string (that contains a `$` symbol) and a variable into a single line that goes into text file.
I'm creating a ps1 from a function.

```psh
function pwd{
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,position=0,mandatory=$true)][String]$Temp,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,position=1,mandatory=$true)][String]$Path,
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,position=2,mandatory=$true)][String]$SubscriptionName
  )

  $NewFilePath = "$Path\newfile.ps1"
  New-Item -ItemType file $NewFilePath -Force 
  Add-Content $NewFilePath '    $TimeStart=Get-Date'
  Add-Content $NewFilePath "    $AccountName=""$($SubscriptionName)"" " #Here's my doubt
}

$ScriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
pwdtest -Temp "String" -Path $ScriptPath -SubscriptionName "mail@something.com"

$ScriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
pwdtest -Temp "String" -Path $ScriptPath -SubscriptionName "mail@something.com"
```

So calling the function `pwd` this way:

```psh
$ScriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
pwd -Temp "String" -Path $ScriptPath -SubscriptionName "mail@something.com"
```

How can I rewrite that line?

```psh
Add-Content $NewFilePath "    $AccountName=""$($AutomationAccount)"" "
```

Because I need to write in the text file this:

```
  $TimeStart=Get-Date
  $AccountName = "mail@something.com"
```

And right now if I use that line I've got this in the text file:

```
  $TimeStart=Get-Date
  ="mail@something.com"
```

How can I say PowerShell `Add-Content` not interpretate the `$AccountName` as a "NULL" value and I need to use it as a content string and not a variable.

I had this idea of combination:

```psh
Add-Content $NewFilePath '    $AccountName=' + " ""$($SubscriptionName)"" "
```

But It doesn't work.

```
Add-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument    '+'.
  At C:\Users\JoseGabriel\test.ps1:10 char:5
  +     Add-Content $NewFilePath '    $AccountName=' + "     ""$($SubscriptionName)"" "
  +       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Content], ParameterBindingException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```psh
Add-Content $NewFilePath "    `$TimeStart=Get-Date"
Add-Content $NewFilePath "    `$AccountName=""$($SubscriptionName)"""
```

Escape characters, Delimiters and Quotes

The PowerShell escape character is the grave-accent(`` ` ``).

The escape character can be used in three ways:

1. When used at the end of a line, it is a continuation character - so the command will continue on the next line.
2. To indicate that the next character following should be passed without substitution. For example `$myVariable` will normally be expanded to display the variables contents but `` `$myVariable `` will just be passed as `$myVariable`.
3. When used inside double quotation marks, the escape character indicates that the following character should be interpreted as a 'special' character.

Source: http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html

Comment: No I didn't know anything about that char. Thanks you very much Ansgar! It worked!

Comment: Alright Thank you for the answer  @MarcKellerman  I didn't know anything about that char.